# Android ROM that can make an app believe the OS is not rooted

Tags: gratis, android-rom

A recent game refuses to run on rooted devices.

I don't know how the game detects that, maybe just looking at the OS name, or trying to use root, or checking for specific files or processes? Probably all of this and more. There is [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devadvance.rootcloakplus) and an [Xposed module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak2) for root cloak, but they are not capable to fool Pokémon Go, so a dedicated distribution would probably be better at this.

I am looking for a CyanogenMod fork or other Android distribution that can hide the fact that the OS is rooted.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Works on Nexus 5
- Must cloak root efficiently. In particular, it must fool Pokémon Go
- Open source strongly preferred
- Bonus if I can choose towards what apps the OS should behave as non-rooted

Comment: Nicolas, essential detail missing: Your device. ROMs are device specific. Apart from that: [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). ROMs don't hide root, [Root Hider](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1021) do :)

Comment: Added, thanks! It seems that no root hider is powerful enough, unfortunately. A generic app can not hide everything that a customized ROM might have modified, that's why a ROM designed specifically with this goal in mind is needed, I believe.

Comment: Maybe. But I've never heard of any ROM shipping with a "generic/configurable root hider" (and if there is such, it would certainly have shown up at least as "lite version" in a separate app) – so I'd be surprised if you get a matching answer. Fingers crossed, though!